# Probability question with expected value and variance. (Involves Markov and Chebyshev's inequalities)

Tags: probability, random-variables, expected-value, variance

> A man bought $4$ stocks, the value of the first stock is $100\$ $ , the second $150\$$, third $50\$$ and the fourth $20\$$. 
> We define $v_i$ to be the value of the stock $i$. 
> The probability for the value of the stock rises in the end of the week is $\frac{\sqrt{v_i}}{60}$ independently from all the other stocks. 
> Let $X$ be the number of stocks the man has won money in the end of the week. 
> Calculate:
> -The probability that the man has won in at least $2$ stocks. 
> -The expected value of $X$, and find an upper bound of the probability you found above using Markov's inequality. 
> -The variance of $X$, and find an upper bound of the probability you found above using Chebyshev inequality.

**My Work**: 
**Calculating $P(X\ge 2)$:** 
$P(X\ge 2) = P(X=2)+P(X=3)+P(X=4) = \frac{\sqrt{100}}{60}\frac{\sqrt{150}}{60}(1-\frac{\sqrt{50}}{60})(1-\frac{\sqrt{20}}{60}) + \frac{\sqrt{150}}{60}\frac{\sqrt{50}}{60}(1-\frac{\sqrt{100}}{60})(1-\frac{\sqrt{20}}{60})+ \dots (\text{All the possibilities of choosing $2$ out of the $4$)} + \frac{\sqrt{100}}{60}\frac{\sqrt{150}}{60}\frac{\sqrt{50}}{60}(1-\frac{\sqrt{20}}{60})+ \dots (\text{All the possibilities of choosing 3 out of the 4)} +\frac{\sqrt{100}}{60}\frac{\sqrt{150}}{60}\frac{\sqrt{50}}{60}\frac{\sqrt{20}}{60}$ 
I'm pretty unsure that this is the most efficient solution or if it's the right one, would appreciate any feedback. 
 
For the next steps,
I thought of defining $I_1,I_2,I_3,I_4$ as indicators of stocks $1$ to $4$, in which each indicator is equal to one if the man has won in the stock and zero if not. 
So $X= \sum^4_{i=1}I_i$ . 
**Expected value calculation:** 
Then I can say that $E(X)=E(\sum^4_{i=1}I_i)=\sum^4_{i=1}E(I_i)=\sum^4_{i=1}P(I_i=1)=\sum^4_{i=1} \frac{\sqrt{v_i}}{60}$ 
**Variance Calculation:** 
$var(X) = E(X^2)-(E(X))^2$ So I need to calculate $E(X^2)$ 

$E(X^2)=E(\sum^4_{i=1}I_i\sum^4_{j=1}I_j) = E(\sum^4_{i=1}I_i^2 + 2 \sum_{i<j}I_iI_j)=E(\sum^4_{i=1}I_i^2) + 2E( \sum_{i<j}I_iI_j)=E(X)+ 2*\sum_{i<j}P(I_i=1)P(I_j=1)=E(X)+2 \sum_{i<j}\frac{\sqrt{v_i}}{60} \frac{\sqrt{v_j}}{60}$ 
**Inequalities:**
I haven't yet tried to calculate that long probability of $P(X\ge 2)$, because I'm pretty unsure of it, and so I still haven't tried to find upper bounds using the inequalities. But I've tried to set the inequalities and finding some trouble with Chebyshev's inequality: 

$P(X\ge 2) \le \frac{E(X)}{2}$ -- Markov's inequality. 
$P(|X-E(X)|\ge a) \le\frac{var(X)}{a^2}$ for any $a>0$, I'm not sure here how can I reach $P(X\ge 2)$.

I am really unsure of this long solution, and would appreciate any approval / dissapproval of any step I made or approach, so I can learn from it and turn it into a better solution. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

On a quick read through, your calculations look good to me, and I think using indicator functions, as you've done, is probably the best way to go about calculating the mean and variance of $\ X\ $.  You can simplify your calculation of the variance, however.  Since $\ I_1, I_2, I_3, I_4\ $ are independent, the variance of their sum is the sum of their variances, so you can avoid having to evaluate your more complicated expression for $\ E\big(X^2\big)\ $

Comment: thanks for the help! I'll try to use this today and make sure that I reach the same answer using both ways. I'm still stuck on Chebyshev's inequality, I've never used it before and not sure how to deal with it for this question, I would appreciate it if you could take a look at it

Comment: Since $\ E(X)<2\ $ then one way of using Chebyshev's inequality is to put $\ a=2-E(X)\ $ in
\begin{align}
\frac{var(X)}{a^2}&\ge P\big(|X-E(X)|\ge a\big)\\
&=P\big(\{X\le E(X)-a\}\cup\{X\ge E(X)+a\}\big)\\
&\ge P\big(X\ge E(X)+a\big)\ ,
\end{align} although if $\ \frac{var(X)}{a^2}\ $ turns out to be not less than $1$, this doesn't really tell you anything.

Comment: Thanks alot I appreciate the help, according to my calculations, $var(X)=0.43022$ and $E(X)=0.5631$. So I get that $\frac{var(X)}{a^2} = 0.2083$. and I had an upper bound of $0.28155$ from Markov's inequality, which led me to see that Chebyshev's inequality is somewhat more accurate, does that make sense?

Comment: It's certainly not true that Chebyshev's inequality will *always* give you a tighter bound than Markov's inequality.  Markov's inequality only applies to random variables that are almost surely non-negative, however, while Chebyshev's inequality isn't subject to that restriction. Neither of them gives a useful bound on $\ P(X\ge a)\ $ unless $\ 0<a<E(X)\ $.